# Nothing happens when trying to install a .run file from the terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm new to linux. I have Ubuntu and I would like to run a .run installer in my Downloads folder. The name of the run file is "xampp.run"
I've read that you first have to run

```
chmod +x xampp.run
```

to change mode to installer and then run

> ./xampp.run

to run the installer. However, nothing happens when I try these. I'm running from root@ubuntu.

This is what I've done in my shell.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on the "nothing happens".

Comment: So, you just get a new prompt.  On Unix, this often just means that no error occurred.  Have you checked any other way whether the installation has been completed?

Comment: Paste in results of following commands: `uname -a`, `file xampp.run`

Comment: result of uname -a is:Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: result of file xampp.run is: xampp.run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu and would be better suited at askubuntu.com, provided the question meets their standards.

Comment: Lots of questions could go to other sites.  It could go to AskUbuntu; it could go to one of ServerFault or SuperUser; it could go to WebMaster; it could go to Unix & Linux; it could stay where it is.  At this stage, I recommend leaving it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) and install XAMPP for x86_64 Linux.

Comment: I have tried both of them to no avail.

Comment: now i got something working after trying it exactly as the 64bit version told me i.e. chmod 755. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.run` files are executables, not unlike windows-installers(M$)

You may need root permission to execute the file.

`su` to `root`, and enter the root password, or use `sudo` before your command

then either `cd` to the directory where the `.run` file is

or use "absolute addressing" and

type in a terminal shell...

```
sh (filename).run
```

Generally you can evoke a help screen (not always) by adding `--help` on the end.

```
sh (filename).run --help
```

(this may give you options to apply to the install script.)

Hope this helps

Comment: Running a compiled executable via `sh` won't work.

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `xampp'

Answer (score 0):

You should download 64bit version of Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

this steps is for ubuntu user

```
sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-1.8.2.0-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.2.0-installer.run
```

(This will extract all the packages to the /opt/lampp directory)

Then start the service

/opt/lampp/lampp start